# Retrofit for Android - include dependencies between calls

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I do have different types of API calls, some of them depend on each other, i.e. they may only start after another one returns. Is there a way in Retrofit (2) to declare these type of dependency? I implemented my calls asynchronously.

Comment: Use RxJava and `zip()` or `combineLatest()` to execute subsequent ops. Of course you can always nest calls, if you are using `Callback`

Comment: Do post solution of your problem .

Comment: @Code_Life what do you mean? I don't have a solution yet ;)

Comment: i meant to say when u have the solution , do share.

Comment: @Code_Life ah, okay - will do.